# Additive differential probability

Tags: block-cipher, differential-analysis

I am studying about additive differential probability.

And I show a paper that is [V.Velichkov et al., The Additive Differential Probability of ARX](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220942468_The_Additive_Differential_Probability_of_ARX).

I have a question in chapter 5.2.

V.Velichkov et al. said that "In general, following the mapping in Table 2, an initial state $S[0]=j \in \{0,2,4,6\}$ will match final states $S[n-1]=j$ and $S[n-1]=j+1$.

I want to know why this is correct.